# Nested SQL to LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have three Tables as

1. Documents(DocumentID, DocumentName)
2. Subjects(SubjectID, SubjectName)
3. DocumentSubjects (DocumentID,SubjectID)

I want to get Documents form Documents Table where SubjectID id is provided as a input 
SQL query for this is

```
  Select * from Documents where 
  DocumentID IN (
  Select DocumentID From DocumentSubjects Where SubjectID= 2 
  );
```

I want this query in LINQ , Please can you help me , Thanks in Advance. :)

Comment: At StackOverflow, you are supposed to try to solve problems yourself and *then* come here and ask, *including* your attempts at solving the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
context.Documents.Where(d=>d.Subjects.Any(s=>s.SubjectID == 2))
```

Or

```
context.Subjects.Where(s=>s.SubjectID == 2).SelectMany(s=>s.Documents).Distinct()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it in a more  'SQL-like way':

```
var result = (from document in context.Documents
              where (from documentsubject in context.DocumentSubjects 
                     where documentsubject.SubjectID == 2
                     select documentsubject.DocumentID)
              .Contains(document.DocumentID)
              select document).ToList();
```